# Pop up Chat Dialog is not working during sent message. from One user to another user

Tags: c#, wpf

Pop up Chat Dialog is not working during sent message. from One user to another user. while chat

```
 MessageData mes = new MessageData(SendMessage);    
 _client = new TcpClient(_remoteIPAddress.ToString(), _port);
 _strm = _client.GetStream();
  CryptoHelper.SendData(_strm, mes);    
 strm.Close();
 client.Close();
 SentMessages.Add("Sent to " + _remoteIPAddress.ToString() + " > " + SendMessage);
```

Comment: There is no question here? What are you trying to do and what is not working (or, more specifically - what do you see that makes you think that something is not working)?

Comment: this code is works only when the two user is online. if user is online but the messenger is not open . so the message cannot be sent . if both user chat messenger is open only it will works.

Comment: How do you expect to send a message to another client that does not have a socket to receive the data? What you describe is exactly what I would expect to happen. If you want the data to persist and be sent later when the client comes on line then you need to send it to an intermediate server that is always able to receive messages.

Comment: Sockets has been used . in this application but the only pblm is not pop up the dialogbox when a messgae receive in another user.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].